# How to generate all the different values in converting a number into a phone vanity letter in C++

Tags: c++

the C++ assignment im working on is to ask the user for a 4 digit number and then the program outputs all the possible vanity letters based on a phone keypad. I am currently stuck on the best way to get the program to work and how to write it. Anyone got any ideas? thanks for the help!

Comment: I have plenty of ideas, however if I were to give them to you then you would not learn as much as if you were to explain me what you have achieved so far and I would nudge you in the right direction and try to make you guess your errors. In short: you want some code? post yours :)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds homework-ish, so I'll only give you an idea:

You need a mapping from each number to the corresponding set of letters. Then you generate the possible permutations for all the different letters corresponding to the respective digits.

For example, for the digit "1", the possible letters are 'A', 'B', and 'C', for the digit "2" they are 'D', 'E', and 'F'. so for the number "12" the possible permutations would be

```
AD
AE
AF
BD
BE
BF
CD
CE
CF
```

Does this help?

Comment: I'd be interested in why you think that's wrong. (You didn't down-vote for no reason, did you?)

Answer (score 1):

Every 4 digit sequence of vanity letters is a vanity letter followed by a 3-digit sequence of vanity letters. Does that give you an idea of how to break it down?

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is a bit rusty, but this should get you pretty close.  The idea here is to use a combination of looping and recursion.  The recursion depth is equal to the length of the phone number, and each level of recursion generates the possible permutations for that and subsequent digits of the phone number.

The code itself is easy - understanding why it works is the hard part :)

```
std::map<char,std::string> letters = new std::map<char,std::string>();
letters.put('1', "ABC");
letters.put('2', "DEF");
... etc ...

std::vector<std::string> all_permutations = new std::vector<std::string>();

void GeneratePermutations( std::string number, int digit, std::string vanity) {
   std::string letters_for_number = letters.get(number[digit - 1]);

   for( int i = 0; i < letters_for_number.size(); i++ ) {
      vanity += letters_for_number[i];
      if ( digit < number.length() ) {
         GeneratePermutations(number, digit + 1, vanity);
      } else {
         all_permutations.add(vanity);
      }
   }
}

void main() {
    GeneratePermutations("1234", 1, "");
}
```

Comment: That's some very rusty C++ you have there. You might want to polish it a bit. OTOH, it didn't hurt in this case, because posting paste-able code as an answer for a homework question is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @sbi - exactly, didn't want it to be TOO correct, but just correct enough that he gets the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo code:

```
main(char[] input) {
  for(int i = 0 .. 3) { letters[i] = letters(input[i]) };

  for(int i = 0 .. letters[0].length) {
    for(int j = 0 .. letters[1].length) {
      for(int k = 0 .. letters[2].length) {
        for(int l = 0 .. letters[3].length) {
          print(letters[0][i], letters[1][j], letters[2][k], letters[3][l]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

char[] letters(char digit) {
  switch (digit) {
    case '2' : {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    ..
    case '9' : {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
  }
}
```